# Remove Object from a list of objects rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails object array of list of users and another object array of list of team_users

I want to show the list of users that are not in team_users but not sure how to go about it .

In my code

```
User.where("users.user_account_type IS NULL or users.user_account_type = 'standard_user'").joins(:user_organizations).where("user_organizations.organization_id = ? AND users.approved = true AND users.locked_at IS NULL", 13)
```

This code returns to me a list of users

```
@team_members = TeamMember.all
```

This returns to me all users that are in team_members. This table has team_member_id as the foreign key for user.id in the User table.

```
User.where("users.user_account_type IS NULL or users.user_account_type = 'standard_user'").joins(:user_organizations).where("user_organizations.organization_id = ? AND users.approved = true AND users.locked_at IS NULL", 13).joins(:team_members).where("team_members.team_member_id != users.id")
```

I tried using this code but it doesnt work. it returns no records.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
in_teams = TeamMember.select(:team_member_id)
users_without_team = User.where.not(id: in_teams)
```

Also you could use hashes instead of strings for the readability:

```
Users.joins(:user_organization).where(approved: true, locked_at: nil, user_organizations: {organization_id: 13})
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you want exactly but this returns only users which dont have the team_users account typ.

```
User.All.Where(x=>x.Users.user_account_type !="team_users")
```